# What does the ‘3’ in Chris Paul’s nickname CP3 stand for?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

Watching the NBA 2021 playoffs with the Phoenix Suns playing and Chris Paul aka CP3 is a fantastic player.  Yet can’t find anywhere that explains what the ‘3’ stands for in his nickname CP3.  Does anyone know?  Is it his jersey number? Could it be that simple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a family related nickname. Chris Paul's father's and older brother's Initials are also CP, making him the third person with initials CP, hence CP3.